# Bound a double integral by a single integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am wondering why we could bound the following double integral by a single integral. We have $0<\alpha<2$:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{|t-s|^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}} dsdt \leq 2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{u^{\frac{a}{2}}}du$$

I think the reasoning is likely to involve symmetry, so I rewrite the double integral into the sum of two other double integral:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{|t-s|^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}} dsdt=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{(t-s)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}} dsdt+\int_{0}^{1} \int_{t}^{1} \frac{1}{(s-t)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}} dsdt
=2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2}{2-\alpha} t^{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}dt$$
Could anyone go further and explain the bound? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered polar coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a substitution: for fixed $t \in [0,1]$ you may take $u = s-t$ to find
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{|t-s|^\alpha} \, ds = \int_{-t}^{1-t} \frac{1}{|u|^\alpha} \, du \le \int_{-1}^0 \frac{1}{|u|^\alpha} \, du + \int_0^1 \frac{1}{|u|^\alpha} \, du = 2\int_0^1 \frac{1}{|u|^\alpha} \, du.$$

Now integrate over $[0,1]$.

Note: I used $\alpha$ instead of $\alpha/2$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!